# Calculate upto 2 decimal in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig script.Whose out put is like below:

```
dump result;

12.334556778990900990993445566
```

Is there any pig inbuilt function where I can restrict it up to 2 decimal places in my result.

```
12.33
```

My last option is to write udf in pig .want to know any other way other than UDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a pig inbuilt function called round.You can try this.

```
Output = ROUND(result*100.0)/100.0;
Dump Output;
```

If your relation result is of type float,then you can use 100f, 100.0 is a Double Constant. For more info,refer to this [link](http://www.qubole.com/resources/cheatsheet/pig-function-cheat-sheet/)